# How to convert a slice of GObjects as a GList to a FFI function from Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi, glib

I am trying to pass a `GObject` to a FFI function from libsecret-1 which requires it be in a `GList`. I have some code that almost compiles, but it complains about the lifetime of the borrowed vaue being too short and not outliving the function. The object itself was created from the FFI using the `wrapper!` macro from the glib crate for Rust. Here is a minimum-viable reproduction that produces the error I am getting:

```
extern crate glib;                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                              
use glib::ffi::GList;
use glib::translate::{ToGlibPtr, GlibPtrDefault, ToGlibContainerFromSlice};

pub fn lock_object_test<'a, W: GlibPtrDefault +
  ToGlibPtr<'a, <W as GlibPtrDefault>::GlibType>>(obj: &'a W) {
    let arr = [obj];
    let slice: (*mut GList, <&W as ToGlibContainerFromSlice<'a, *mut GList>>::Storage) = 
        ToGlibContainerFromSlice::to_glib_none_from_slice(&arr[..]);
    // Would pass slice.0 here as a *mut GList argument to FFI
}
```

The GList should just be a shared reference that is only needed for the duration of the call to the FFI function so I am not sure why it thinks the lifetime need to live beyond the function. The error triggers on the `&arr[..]` due to it being borrowed for longer than the life of `arr`.

Also, any tips on how to make this less wordy would be nice.

Comment: @cafce25 Apologies for that oversight. I've added the missing dependencies and it compiles for me in its own, dedicated file now. I originally was going to add the use-case for slice, but that pulls in some FFI code to call a C function with several arguments and I felt added a lot of extra noise to the MVE above. Here is the function I am calling: https://developer-old.gnome.org/libsecret/unstable/SecretService.html#secret-service-lock-sync. I can call that function and pass ptr::null_mut() as the second argument to it as long as I comment out the line creating the GList slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you specify the *caller* can choose a lifetime `'a` for which all of these bounds have to hold, but the caller can only specify lifetimes that live from before the call to after the function returned. But `arr` doesn't live that long.

You can use higher ranked trait bounds (HRTB) to specify that `W` has to implement `ToGlibPtr` for any lifetime, not just lifetimes specified by the caller.

```rust
use glib::ffi::GList;
use glib::translate::{GlibPtrDefault, ToGlibPtr, ToGlibContainerFromSlice};
pub fn lock_object_test<W> (obj: &W)
where
    for<'a> W: GlibPtrDefault + ToGlibPtr<'a, <W as GlibPtrDefault>::GlibType>
{
    let arr = [obj];
    let (ptr, _zstorage): (*mut GList, <&W as ToGlibContainerFromSlice<*mut GList>>::Storage) = 
        ToGlibContainerFromSlice::to_glib_none_from_slice(&arr[..]);
    // pass ptr here as a *mut GList argument to FFI
}
```

Comment: This exactly resolved the issue with a good explanation. It also fixes the code given in the other answer. When were HRTBs added to stable Rust?

Comment: They've always been there since 1.0. They were [added in November 2014](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18639)

Comment: I'm just surprised I don't recall running into them yet. Your solution was perfect, though I did tweak it slightly. I broke up the where clause to only use the HRTB for the trait that needed it. The rest of the code which I omitted from the OP worked as is.

Comment: Well HRTB are rarely needed. That's why you don't see them often, their main usecase the `Fn` family of traits has special syntax sugar which hides them and other usecases are few and far apart.

Answer (score -3):

The error you're encountering is due to Rust's borrow checker ensuring that the borrowed value (&arr[..]) doesn't outlive the reference itself (arr). In this case, Rust doesn't know how long the reference arr will be needed, so it assumes that you're trying to use the borrowed value outside its expected lifetime.

To address this issue, you can use the std::mem::ManuallyDrop wrapper to temporarily extend the lifetime of the arr variable. Here's a modified version of your code that avoids the lifetime issue and is less wordy:

```
use glib::translate::*;
use glib::GlibPtrDefault;
use libc::GList;
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

pub fn lock_object_test<'a, W>(obj: &'a W)
where
    W: GlibPtrDefault + ToGlibPtr<'a, <W as GlibPtrDefault>::GlibType>,
{
    // Create a ManuallyDrop to extend the lifetime of 'arr'.
    let arr = ManuallyDrop::new([obj]);

    // Convert the ManuallyDrop reference to a GList.
    let slice = arr.as_ref();
    let slice_ptr: (*mut GList, <&W as ToGlibContainerFromSlice<'a, *mut GList>>::Storage) =
        ToGlibContainerFromSlice::to_glib_none_from_slice(slice);

    // Pass slice_ptr.0 as a *mut GList argument to FFI.
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    // Example usage:
    // let obj = ...; // Create your GObject here.
    // lock_object_test(&obj);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, copying your example verbatim still triggered the error for me. The borrowed value from `arr.as_ref()` which was bound at `ManuallyDrop::new([obj])` does not live long enough. I am using Rust 1.71.0.

Comment: @penguin359 yea that's what I would have expected, when the `arr` goes out of scope so do references to it, that doesn't get changed by `ManuallyDrop` I wouldn't expect this to work.

Comment: Hmm.. 

how about trying use the ToGlibPtr trait to convert each GObject in the slice to a *mut GObject, and then manually construct the GList?

Comment: Something like that:

// Function to create a GList from a slice of GObject references
fn create_glist(objects: &[&dyn IsA<glib::Object>]) -> *mut GList {
    let mut glist_ptr: *mut GList = std::ptr::null_mut();

    for obj in objects.iter() {
        // Convert each object to *mut GObject
        let obj_ptr = obj.to_glib_full();
        
        // Append it to the GList
        glist_ptr = unsafe { g_list_append(glist_ptr, obj_ptr as *mut c_void) };
    }

    glist_ptr
}

Comment: @user3527282 I had considered that, but I looked at the source for the ToGlibContainerFromSlice trait and that is basically what it already does so I don't think doing manually. It uses the ToGlibPtr trait to convert each entry and then adds them to a GList with the native glib API.